# Why is my Android app crashing on orientation change?

Tags: android, xml, layout

For my main activity, I have got two layout files. One is for portrait mode and the other one for landscape mode.
These are the locations of my xml files.

For portrait mode:

```
res/layout/activity_main.xml
```

For landscape mode:

```
res/layout-land/activity-main.xml
```

I have tested these configurations and they work perfectly on higher Android devices. The problem is that, for example, on Android 1.6 the app crashes when switching to landscape mode.
What's wrong here? Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: They should have the same name.  Yours are different.  One has an underscore and the other a hyphen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the name of the xml file in layout-land to

```
res/layout-land/activity_main.xml
```

The names are not matching, hence the error. Change it from `activity-main.xml` to `activity_main.xml` (replace hyphen with undescore). You should be fine now.